# How do I broadcast a message to one or many receivers in C++ on Linux?

Tags: c++, linux, ipc, broadcast

I have a GPS sending the position as a text message in the NMEA: [GPGGA](https://docs.novatel.com/OEM7/Content/Logs/GPGGA.htm) format via TCP/IP at a fixed rate of 100 Hz.

In a project I work on a 3rd party needs the position values but would prefer to not parse the GPPGA messages themselves.

I therefore wants to create a program that runs in its separate process (microservice?) and reads in the GPPGA messages, parses them and "broadcast" the position values via a simpler protocol.

I have decided on using protocol buffers for the position values (over plain C/C++ struct):

```
syntax = "proto3";
package  GPS;

message GeodeticPosition {
  double unixEpoch = 1; // the number of seconds that have elapsed since January 1, 1970 at midnight UTC time minus the leap seconds.
  double  latitudeDegrees = 2; 
  double longitudeDegrees = 3;
  double altitudeMeters   = 4;  
}
```

But how should I implement the "broadcasting" of the messages?

So far I am sending them as UDP packets using a socket.

Is there some framework in C++ on Linux I can use that is well suited for this task?

Comment: UDP multicast is an option, as is a simple message queuing system like mosquitto or zeromq. Depends on where the clients live, mostly.

Comment: GPS updates at 100Hz? What device that can fix at that speed, please?

Comment: asking for "some framework" is offtopic

Comment: Why reinvent the wheel? gpsd exists, and is battle proven software doing exactly what you intend to do?

Comment: its basically just a matter of setting `SO_BROADCAST` as socket option, not clear why you think you need a framework when you are already using UDP via raw sockets

Comment: You can use dbus

Comment: I second sending out the info via UDP (preferably multicast, but broadcast would work too).  No need to overcomplicate things, and at 100Hz you probably don't want to involve a lot of middleware.